# How to upload a File in Puppeteer where another button is used to invoke the file directory instead of the original File Input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, puppeteer, node.js-fs

I've been trying to automate comment for facebook plugin comment sections.
for example [this](https://www.facebook.com/plugins/feedback.php?app_id=190712595201460&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fx%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2F%3Fversion%3D46%23cb%3Df2ce05b76e5514%26domain%3Dchapmanganato.to%26is_canvas%3Dfalse%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fchapmanganato.to%252Ff323645923319a%26relation%3Dparent.parent&color_scheme=light&container_width=853&height=100&href=http%3A%2F%2Fmanganelo.com%2Fmanga%2Fen937931&locale=en_US&numposts=10&sdk=joey&width)

I can comment but I am unable to attach an image with puppeteer.

So the actual input with id #js_1 or input[type=file] doesn't work but the wrapper div around the input are clickable and they open up the file directory.

```
    let inputFileWrapper = '.UFIPhotoAttachLinkWrapper' //div around input
    let inputFile = '#js_1' //file input

    await page.click(inputFileWrapper) //This opens up the file directory
    // await page.click(inputFile)  //This is the input element but doesn't work
```

But after opening up the file directory the file chooser just stops because the clickable element to open the file is not input.

```
    const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
        page.waitForFileChooser(),
        page.click(inputFileWrapper), 
        // page.click(inputFile) 
    ])
    let imagePath = 'D:/filePath/file.jpg';
    await fileChooser.accept([imagePath])
```

I don't use both the above code at the same time. The first code block just shows how the file Directory to choose file opens.
and the second code is the default way of uploading files in puppeteer. but it doesn't work because "inputFileWrapper" is not the actual input element and "inputFile" doesn't open the file directory.

So is there a way to choose a file after opening the file Directory manually with page.click()?

or are there any alternate way to do this?

This is the structure of the input

```
<div class="UFICommentAttachmentButtons clearfix">

<div class="_r1a UFIPhotoAttachLinkWrapper _m" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-alignh="center"   data-tooltip-content="Attach a Photo" role="presentation" id="js_i" aria-describedby="js_h">  

<span class="UFICommentPhotoIcon" tabindex="-1"><div class="_3jk">

<input accept="image/*, image/heic, image/heif" aria-label="Attach a Photo" class="_n _5f0v" title="Attach a Photo" type="file" name="file" id="js_1">

</div>
</span>
</div>
::after
</div>
```

THIS IS THE WHOLE CODE

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const fs = require('fs/promises')

async function cmtOnPost(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
        browserWSEndpoint: "webSocketDebuggerUrl"
        });
    console.log("Connected...")
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    let url = 'https://www.facebook.com/plugins/feedback.php?app_id=190712595201460&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fx%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2F%3Fversion%3D46%23cb%3Df2ce05b76e5514%26domain%3Dchapmanganato.to%26is_canvas%3Dfalse%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fchapmanganato.to%252Ff323645923319a%26relation%3Dparent.parent&color_scheme=light&container_width=853&height=100&href=http%3A%2F%2Fmanganelo.com%2Fmanga%2Fen937931&locale=en_US&numposts=10&sdk=joey&width'
    
    
    await page.goto(url)
    console.log('Page Loaded...')




    let commentBox = '.notranslate'
    let commentContent = 'Nice'


    // Put Text in Input Box
    await page.click(commentBox)
    await page.type(commentBox,commentContent)
    
    
    
    // This is the element wrapped around input[type=file]
    let inputFileWrapper = '.UFIPhotoAttachLinkWrapper' 
    let inputFile = '#js_1'
    // await page.click(inputFileWrapper)
    // await page.click(inputFile)


    
    // await new Promise((re,rej) => setTimeout(()=> console.log("AFTER 4 sec"),4000));
    
    const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
        page.waitForFileChooser(),
        // page.click(inputFile),
        page.click(inputFileWrapper),

    ])
    let imagePath = 'D:/FILE/PATH/filename.jpg';
    await fileChooser.accept([imagePath])
    
    // await new Promise((re,rej) => setTimeout(()=> console.log("AFTER 4 sec"),4000)),
    
    console.log("FILE UPLOADED")
    


    // Post the comment
    await page.click('body > div > div > div > div > div > div._4uyl._1zz8._2392.clearfix > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div._4uym > div > div._ohf.rfloat > span > button')
}
cmtOnPost()
```

I've also tried to disable the CSS of the page by using this code. It removes the whole Head tag

```
   await page.evaluate(()=>{
        return document.head.parentNode.removeChild(document.head)
   })
```

And the fileChooser works this time with the Real Input instead of clickable one.
but if you submit the comment. only the text content is posted but not the image.

I think there might be some functions in the head tag for that which attach the file to the submit text.

would this work if you remove the css Styles from the page(I'm removing the whole head tag here)?